# Unable to get Joiners to work in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am new to optaplanner and was trying to create a modified version of the employee scheduling example. There is something I am doing wrong on the use of Joiners because I am unable to get them to work correctly and was hoping someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Like the example, I have a Shift class which has an Employee class as an instance variable and I have an Availability class which has an Employee class as an instance variable. I implemented a Constraint function just like the example:

```
    Constraint unavailableEmployee (ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Shift.class)
                .join(Availability.class,
                    Joiners.equal(Shift::getEmployee,Availability::getEmployee))
                .filter((shift,availability) -> availability.getAvailabilityType() == AvailabilityType.UNAVAILABLE)
                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("Unavailable employee");

    }
```

However, using this function does not work and an employee is scheduled for shifts where they are unavailable.

I changed the constraint method to

```
    Constraint unavailableEmployee(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Shift.class)
                .join(Availability.class)
                .filter((shift, availability) -> (shift.getEmployee().getEmployeeId().equals(availability.getEmployee().getEmployeeId()) && availability.getAvailabilityType() == AvailabilityType.UNAVAILABLE))
                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                .asConstraint("Unavailable employee");
    }
```

This approach basically joined within the Filter. When I did this it worked, so the problem must be related to how I have tried to use the Joiner to setup. My understanding is the way I have it working is less efficient because it is evaluating all permutations while if I had the Joiner class in place there would be fewer evaluations.

Here are the two domain classes I am attempting to join

Shift.Class

```
package com.guidematcher.domain;


import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.entity.PlanningEntity;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.lookup.PlanningId;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningVariable;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@PlanningEntity
public class Shift {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @PlanningId
    private String shiftId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private LocalDateTime shiftStart;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private LocalDateTime shiftEnd;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private EmployeeType requiredEmployeeType;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String requiredEmployeeTypeDesc;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @PlanningVariable
    private Employee employee;

    public Shift() {

    }

    public Shift (LocalDateTime shiftStart,LocalDateTime shiftEnd, String requiredEmployeeTypeDesc) {
        this(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),shiftStart,shiftEnd,requiredEmployeeTypeDesc,null);
    }


    public Shift (String shiftId,LocalDateTime shiftStart,LocalDateTime shiftEnd,String requiredEmployeeTypeDesc, Employee employee) {
        this.shiftId = shiftId;
        this.shiftStart = shiftStart;
        this.shiftEnd = shiftEnd;
        this.setRequiredEmployeeTypeDesc(requiredEmployeeTypeDesc);
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public void setRequiredEmployeeTypeDesc(String requiredEmployeeTypeDesc) {
        this.requiredEmployeeTypeDesc = requiredEmployeeTypeDesc;
        this.requiredEmployeeType = EmployeeType.getEmployeeTypeByDesc(requiredEmployeeTypeDesc);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getShiftId() + "-" + this.getRequiredEmployeeType().getEmployeeTypeDesc() + " " + this.getShiftStart();
    }
}
```

Availability.class

```
package com.guidematcher.domain;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.lookup.PlanningId;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Availability {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @PlanningId
    private String availabilityId;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    LocalDate availabilityDate;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    AvailabilityType availabilityType;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    Employee employee;

    public Availability() {}

    public Availability(String availabilityId, Employee employee, LocalDate availabilityDate, AvailabilityType availabilityType ) {
        this.availabilityId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.employee = employee;
        this.availabilityDate = availabilityDate;
        this.availabilityType = availabilityType;
    }


}
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding here - constraints can not prevent OptaPlanner from assigning any particular value; they only tell OptaPlanner that a particular assignment should be penalized or rewarded. Hopefully, with this information, the solver will be able to find a solution which does not make the unwanted assignment. But maybe it does not - there are no guarantees.

Your `Joiner` and your `filter` aren't functionally equivalent - the `Joiner` will use `Employee.equals(...)`, while the filter is implementing some custom logic. Your code snippets do not show `Employee.equals(...)` and seeing the `@Getter` annotations, I am assuming it is auto-generated as well. Or, if it's not there, then it uses `Employee` identity, where the filter compares by `id`.

Anyway, if I had to guess, the difference in behavior comes from the fact that the equality logic is different than the filter logic. If the two were the same, there should have been *zero* functional difference; the `Joiner` should give the same score, just faster.